# C# Reading a string from a .txt file

Tags: c#

A fragment of my .txt file looks like this:

```
18  Ladders/ladder_trigger (18 triggers) (18 enabled)
17  assets/prefabs/player/player_model.prefab/collision (0 triggers) (1 enabled)
17  assets/prefabs/misc/xmas/poweredlights/xmas.advanced.lights.deployed.prefab
(0 triggers) (17 enabled)
```

There are +1000 lines and their order is always random.
My problem is that I'm trying to get an int which consists of the number of **enabled** values from a line which always contains text **assets/prefabs/player/player_model.prefab/collision** and output it in console.
There is always only 1 line containing **assets/prefabs/player/player_model.prefab/collision** but the number of **enabled** values may differ and it's position in the text file is always different.
I've tried to check a whole text file for this certain string and then try to figure it out from there on how to get that number but I have no idea on how to do that.
Here's a part of my code which works fine but only for checking *if* the file contains that string or not but not for getting the number after that.

```
            string[] words = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\azir\Desktop\KelosRPR\Physics.Colliders.Objects.txt").Split(' ');
            string wordtobesearched = "assets/prefabs/player/player_model.prefab/collision";
            bool condition = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].Contains(wordtobesearched) == true)
                {
                    condition = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    condition = false;
                }
            }
            if (condition == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} found in data", wordtobesearched);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} not found in data", wordtobesearched);
            }
```

Comment: Can you share you code?  Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: @StenPetrov can you tell us what the user has done with attempting this task and where their mistake/s are?

Comment: As soon as you find the line containing the search term, you break out of the loop instead of searching the line for the integer.

Comment: Thanks Rufus L, it worked for me.

Comment: You want to read it line by line, look for the pattern, when found get the number, and exit the loop. No need to read all the words from the file into an array. That is inefficient.

Comment: @StenPetrov The question was closed *before* code was added to the question, not after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to find the `enabled` number. Here's an example.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\azir\Desktop\KelosRPR\Physics.Colliders.Objects.txt");
var wordtobesearched = "assets/prefabs/player/player_model.prefab/collision";
var regex = new Regex($"{wordtobesearched}.*?\\((\\d+) enabled\\)");
var number = int.Parse(regex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value);
```